# problems to handle more than one (return) parameter in main()

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, return, program-entry-point

I'm rewriting an old keyword-scanner from Python2 to Python3 and have problems to handle more than one return parameter in my final main()-function.

```
def scanner_pref():

dork = input('Dork: ')
number = input('Number of sites: ')

return dork, number
```

So, I need to return dork and number to the next function

```
def scanner(dork, number):

url = "http://www.google.de/search"
payload = {'q': dork, 'start':'0', 'num': int(number) *10}
```

[..]

so the scanner can proceed with the given parameters of payload.

But when I try to write the main()-function, it can't handle the scanner-function, because it suddendly requires the numbers parameter. see below

```
def main():
pref = scanner_pref()
scan = scanner(pref) <-- 
parser(h3tag=scan)
```

I don't really understand why scan = scanner(pref, ?) requires the number parameter when it receives the information from the scanner(pref) above and doesn't really care about the dork-parameter.

If I remove "number" from scanner_pref(), move it back to scanner(..) it works fine and no error or warning message appears.

```
def scanner_pref():

dork = input('Dork: ')

return dork
```

#

```
def scanner(dork, number):
url = "http://www.google.de/search"
number = ("Number of sites: ")
payload = {'q': dork, 'start':'0', 'num': int(number) *10}
```

#

```
def main():
pref = scanner_pref()
scan = scanner(pref)
parser(h3tag=scan)
```

works fine and without problems

Comment: You could format the main function as follows: `pref, number = scanner_pref()` then you can call your scanner method with those 2 variables

Comment: @Jordan sorry for the late reply, but thanks for your help, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`scanner(dork, number)` takes two arguments.

When you call `pref = scanner_pref()` the values `dork` and `number` are stored in `perf` as a tuple. When you pass `pref` to `scanner` you are still only passing one argument, a tuple with two values.

you have two easy options

```
pref_dork, pref_number = scanner_pref()
scan = scanner(pref_dork, pref_number)
```

or

```
pref = scanner_pref()
scan = scanner(pref[0],perf[1])
```